# @GetMapping, ambigious mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to create several routes for `@GetMapping`. For example, `localhost:8080/tasks` and `localhost:8080/tasks/?status=...`

So I created several methods as below.

**Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/tasks", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ExposesResourceFor(Task.class)
public class TaskRepresentation {

    private final TaskResource taskResource;

    public TaskRepresentation(TaskResource taskResource) {
        this.taskResource = taskResource;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> getAllTasks() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(this.taskResource.findAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> getTasksStatus(@RequestParam("status") int status) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(this.taskResource.getTasksByStatus(status), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

**Resource**

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "task")
public interface TaskResource extends JpaRepository<Task, String> {

    @GetMapping
    List<Tache> getTasksByStatus(@RequestParam int status);

}
```

**Error**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'taskRepresentation' method 
public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.miage.tache.boundary.TacheRepresentation.getTasksStatus(int)
to {GET /tasks, produces [application/json]}: There is already 'taskRepresentation' bean method
```

(The only solution is to create only one route for @GetMapping with optionnal params?)

Can you help me ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coming from the other answer, as this one's more specific.
You can narrow down your endpoint mapping by specifying the necessary query parameters.

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> getAllTasks() {
   return ResponseEntity.ok().body(this.taskResource.findAll());
}

@GetMapping(params = "status")
public ResponseEntity<?> getAllTasksWithStatus(@RequestParam("status") final int status) {
   return ResponseEntity.ok().body(this.taskResource.getTasksByStatus(status));
}
```

Docs [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#params--).

Note: as params is an array, you can specify multiple values with

```
@GetMapping(params = { "status", "date" })
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/tasks", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ExposesResourceFor(Task.class)
public class TaskRepresentation {

    private final TaskResource taskResource;

    public TaskRepresentation(TaskResource taskResource) {
        this.taskResource = taskResource;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> getTasksStatus(@RequestParam(value="status", required=false) Integer status) {
        if(status==null){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(this.taskResource.findAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(this.taskResource.getTasksByStatus(status.intValue()), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, i know. Poster has declared 2 controllers for the same route which has optional status request param and causing ambigious controller exception. Please read my solution carefully. I am suggesting to create a single controller to get request param which is optional. If status is not provided, call `findAll()` otherwise call `getTasksByStatus()`. I don't see any issue here. Can you please tell me what i have suggested wrongly?

Comment: Actually, it solves the issue because now their is only 1 controller for route `/tasks`. So i don't think there is any ambiguity in routing so solution should work. Why do you think, this is not the answer?

Comment: Ok, this will, you're right. I didn't see you collapsing those controllers into one, my mistake.

Comment: @Andronicus your mistake cost me 2 downvotes for a working solution. Please be careful before actually putting a negative comment.

Comment: @ArpitAgrawal indeed this solution seems to work. However, I don't know if it's me, but the null test is a bit dirty no? xD Spring don't have methods to do this properly (to test if I a parameter is present or not)?

Comment: @N.Lamblin I don't think anything can be done here because it's a request param. What spring does for you is set it to null since its optional. I personally don't think anything can be done here. But let's see if more experienced people from community have any views regarding this. If this works, can you please mark this as an answer?

Comment: Yep i will mark it as answer, and post another question to know if spring own methods to test if a parameter exists or not. Thanks.