# Check if a parameter is specified or not into the URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

It is possible to test if a parameter exists or not into an URL with Spring?

Below, my current code, but maybe that `if(status == null)` is a bit dirty right?

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> getAllTasks(@RequestParam(value = "status", required = false) Integer status) {
    if(status == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(this.taskResource.findAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(this.tacheResource.getTachesByEtat(status), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

The method `getAllTasks()` will be call in different cases:

- localhost:8080/tasks
- localhost:8080/tasks/?status=...

That's why I try to find another way to do this test.

Can you help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: I would stick with LppEdd's solution

Comment: it is mostly opinion based, and you can use `Objects.isNull(status)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on your Java version, you can use `Optional` and `isPresent()` (but you'll have to get the value from your `status` variable using `status.get()`):

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> getAllTasks(@RequestParam("status") Optional<Integer> status) {
    if(!status.isPresent()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(this.taskResource.findAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(this.tacheResource.getTachesByEtat(status.get()), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

*Look down, at the end of this answer, for the better solution.*

The best approach is following the *single responsibility* pattern.

As your URL could be called using two different ways, why not splitting it, and letting each one implement its own logic?

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> getAllTasks() {
   return ResponseEntity.ok().body(this.taskResource.findAll());
}

@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> getAllTasksWithStatus(@RequestParam("status") final int status) {
   return ResponseEntity.ok().body(this.tacheResource.getTachesByEtat(status));
}
```

Spring will handle this beautifully.

Note that when you use a single, `value` property with an `Annotation`, you don't need to explicitly specify it.

Edit: being that this can have the effect of producing a mapping collision, an even better alternative to `@RequestParam` is using `@PathVariable` for the `*WithStatus` endpoint.

```
@GetMapping("/status/{status}")
public ResponseEntity<?> getAllTasksWithStatus(@PathVariable("status") final int status) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(this.tacheResource.getTachesByEtat(status));
}
```

---

When dealing with complex, long, URLs, there are two roads to take.
Use `@PathVariable`(s), such as

```
/{status}/{date}/{name}
```

Or go for a `POST` HTTP request. Here you can customize the `body` as you prefer. I usually go for POST requests when dealing with complex HTTP calls.

---

Last edit, hopefully:
you can narrow down mapping by specifying the wanted query params.

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> getAllTasks() {
   return ResponseEntity.ok().body(this.taskResource.findAll());
}

@GetMapping(params = "status")
public ResponseEntity<?> getAllTasksWithStatus(@RequestParam("status") final int status) {
   return ResponseEntity.ok().body(this.tacheResource.getTachesByEtat(status));
}
```

No more conflicts ;)

As `params` is an array, you can specify multiple values with

```
@GetMapping(params = { "status", "date" })
```

Comment: How would you handle same URL but optional param in this case, since your 2 controller points to same URL. Don't you think it will create ambiguity?

Comment: @ArpitAgrawal there is a trade off here. The "optional" query parameter is no more optional, in favor of a cleaner solution, architecturally speaking.

Comment: @LppEdd Indeed, this is the best solution for me. However, I got a an error : "Ambigious mapping". you can find my problem here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54676727/getmapping-ambigious-mapping/54676857#54676857

Comment: @N.Lamblin let me fire up a Spring project.

Comment: @N.Lamblin check if the proposed solution is ok for you. If changing your URLs schema is not possible, the solution of Optional is the one to go for. However I think that optional parameters should not be used

Comment: @N.Lamblin I just thought about another interesting one. Let me know what you think about the one above.

Comment: The only problem I see with the solution of @PathVariable is if I need several parameters in the future. For exemple status, date and name. I need to create an url like `/status/{status}/date/{date}/name/{name}`. It is a bit strange no? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @N.Lamblin solution found. See my edit. Look how I added the ("/") only to the first endpoint, getAllTasks. You just need to call the endpoint with "/". Do you think it's acceptable?

Comment: @N.Lamblin I also gave my opinion on complex URLs.

Comment: Your last edit is the perfect answer! Now I have to find how to specified several parameters (to understand and learn correctly Spring). Somethink like `@GetMapping(params = "status", params = "date")`.

Comment: @N.Lamblin btw, thank you for this "challenge". It was fun writing this answer.

Comment: @LppEdd big thanks !!!! Where do you find this information? On documentation? Because I don't found them.

Comment: @ArpitAgrawal Look the answer :).

Comment: @N.Lamblin I found it by reading the RequestMapping documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#params--

Comment: @N.Lamblin I also answered to your other question, for reference purposes. It will be visited more times in the future.

Comment: @N.Lamblin yes, i also saw this here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853035/create-two-method-for-same-url-pattern-with-different-arguments . Yes. Indeed a good way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Optional` in requestParam annotation. `@RequestParam("status") Optional<String> status`
After that you can check if status is present: `status.ifPresent()`